# Haystack + solr duplicate on update

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm new to haystack/solr so this is likely a newbie error. I am using solr with haystack.

When I run update_index, it seems to be duplicating the records. I am getting:

```
get() returned more than one Doctor -- it returned 3!
```

for this piece of code:

```
self._object = self.searchindex.read_queryset().get(pk=self.pk)
```

if I run update_index again, the number return increases by one and if I run rebuild_index, it will work showing only one record until I update again.

So from that, It seems that update_index is duplicating records in the index. How do I get it from not doing that?

Here is my haystack search index:

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Doctor, Zipcode
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.conf import settings

class DoctorIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')
    specialty = indexes.MultiValueField()
    condition = indexes.MultiValueField()
    procedure = indexes.MultiValueField()
    premium = indexes.BooleanField()
    location = indexes.LocationField(model_attr='main_office__location')

    latitude = indexes.DecimalField(indexed=False)
    longitude = indexes.DecimalField(indexed=False)
    docid = indexes.IntegerField()
    slugify_name = indexes.CharField(indexed=False)
    rendered = indexes.CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)
    premium_rendered = indexes.CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)
    include = indexes.BooleanField(indexed=False)

    def get_model(self):
        return Doctor

    def prepare_specialty(self, obj):
        return ["%s %s"%((specialty.parent.name if specialty.parent else ""), specialty.name) for specialty in obj.specialty.all()]

    def prepare_condition(self, obj):
        return [condition.name for condition in obj.conditions.all()]

    def prepare_procedure(self, obj):
        return [procedure.name for procedure in obj.procedures.all()]

    def prepare_premium(self, obj):
        return obj.display()['premium']

    def prepare_latitude(self, obj):
        return obj.main_office.lat

    def prepare_longitude(self, obj):
        return obj.main_office.lon

    def prepare_docid(self,obj):
        return obj.id

    def prepare_slugify_name(self,obj):
        return obj.slugify_name()

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(specialty__search_include=True)
```

Here is my solr schema: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d5b011ca7fa0f3f3e29

I've done a lot of googling, but can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: Are there identical values in the `id` field in the index? Are there any id fields added at all? This seems to be an issue where the uniqueKey field isn't really unique at all ..

Comment: @MatsLindh Where is the uniquekey field set? I thought it used the id of my Doctor object. I didn't manually set an id if that is needed. Where is it set? (sorry. I'm brand new to haystack/solr)

Comment: It's set in your schema.xml (`id` and `uniqueKey`). If you have distinct values in the `id` column in each document, a new document will be added. If a document with the same value in the `id` field exists, it should be updated instead (by default). So check what the `id` field contains for the duplicate documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this one was tricky to track down, but the problem was actually in my index_queryset function.

This:

```
return self.get_model().objects.filter(specialty__search_include=True)
```

should actually be this:

```
return self.get_model().objects.filter(specialty__search_include=True).distinct()
```

That function had duplicates in it and was causing my error, not the solr schema like I had thought. Specialty is a ManyToManyField.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue.
According to this [topic](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/615) it is necessary to remove `.pyc` files. Inside of a project simply do the next (for Linux):

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -type f -delete
```